# Effects of anisotropy and non-homogeneity in the universe's symmetries...?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, spacetime, symmetry, universe

I was reading Philip W Anderson's essay "More is Different" (https://www.tkm.kit.edu/downloads/TKM1_2011_more_is_different_PWA.pdf) and at some point he links the isotropy and homogeneity of space and matter with fundamental symmetries of nature:

> „By symmetry we mean the existence of different viewpoints from which the system appears the same. It is only slightly overstating the case to say that physics is the study of symmetry. The first demonstration of the power of this idea may have been by Newton, who may have asked himself the question: What if the matter here in my hand obeys the same laws as that up in the sky—that is, what if space and matter are homogeneous and isotropic?“

Therefore, does it mean that if space and matter were anisotropic and non-homogeneous, our local symmetries and laws of physics would be different elsewhere? Are there models or metrics of spacetime (or the universe in general) where this would happen (a model that would imply space and matter anisotropy and non-homogeneity)?

Comment: See Noether's Theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem#:~:text=Noether's%20theorem%20or%20Noether's%20first,1915%20and%20published%20in%201918. In essence, if we give up homogeneity, then momentum conservation is gone. If we give up isotropy, then there is no angular momentum conservation. If we give up on time translation symmetry, then energy stops being a locally conserved quantity. None of the above would bode particularly well for the structure of the universe, even though the universe does not conserve energy on the cosmological scale.

Comment: The FLRW metric with these symmetries do not describe local physics anyway. All local 'realistic' matter distributions break these symmetries

Comment: Didn't go through the pdf. By fundamental symmetries of nature, do you also include internal symmetries?

Comment: @KP99 Yes, I would say that

Comment: @FlatterMann and can other symmetries be affected by giving up homogeneity and isotropy (like Poincaré, Lorentz, diffeomorphism and CPT invariances)?

Comment: The problem is symmetry-breaking. We can only have a universe as seen if we assume that the fundamental local symmetry is that of empty space. But empty space creates local Lorentz symmetry, which then creates matter, which breaks this symmetry.

Comment: @FlatterMann but what do we mean when we say that matter breaks the local lorentz invariance (if it were really broken we should have different laws of physics in different frames of reference when matter is present, which does not happen)?

Comment: Yes, Lorentz symmetry is broken inside of matter.

Comment: @FlatterMann but if the local Lorentz symmetry was really broken, Einstein's theory of relativoty would not be valid in those regimes

Comment: It isn't. Special relativity describes the motion in vacuum. It does not describe the dynamics in the bulk of matter systems. But then... neither did Newtonian mechanics. A body in motion inside a body of air or water will not stay in motion. That's part of the genius of Newton... he could see that we have to distinguish between the free dynamics and matter effects that break relativity.

Comment: @FlatterMann and could there be spacetimes where the presence of matter (perhaps with certain distributions or configurations) would break fundamental symmetries (like global and local Poincaré, Lorentz, diffeomorphism, CPT and translational invariances)? And if that is possible, then, wouldn't fundamental laws of physics change in these scenarios as a result of the breaking of these important symmetries?

Comment: There is nothing "fundamental" about the physics inside matter. All of those effects are emergent.